# How to implement countdown timer based function calling in php?

Tags: php

I am doing a project in which i have to do some updations over database every hour .
So what should i use for this ..
Should i simply use php as updations will be done only at server side .
Or any other suggestion that will be better than my approach ?

Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something that is done each hour, you need a scheduler. Look at the MySQL EVENT, the linux cron or the windows scheduler.

Some webhosts do not offer access to these facilities. You can then try to workaround by having a php page check when the job was last run, and run it again if needed. Offcourse this only works if your site has visitors - no visitors = the page does not get executed.

Drupal and other CMS have this php-cron-simulator in their code.

Comment: can u please elaborate about how this scheduler can be implemented ?Actually i am not using any CMS ?

Comment: My answer already contains two hints: 1/ check when the job was last run, and run it again if needed. 2/ for more inspiration, or ready-made code, look at the Drupal sourcecode (or any other CMS). Have you tried either?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a job for cron (assuming *nix).

Answer (score 0):

create php file for updation . :-)

if you want you  can write a log on file or db using php.

You can run the php file using `CRON JOB` and set it to run for evry hour